# AWS S3 upload failing with error > The bucket does not allow ACLs\n\tstatus code: 400

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, acl, bucket

I'm using aws-sdk-go@v1.44.156 and built a plugin using it. Im using plugin to upload the files to s3 bucket. This bucket has acl turned off.
Now when I use aws cli to upload file it works alright. But using this plugin, I'm getting `The bucket does not allow ACLs\n\tstatus code: 400`. I explored on aws documentation and found out that in this plugin I made, I was passing private as a default value for acl and hence it was failing. I tried passing acl as blank and it gave 400 bad request. Then I changed few things and passed `bucket-owner-full-control` as acl value and it started working.
Now my question is

1. According to aws [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/acl-overview.html#CannedACL), private is the default value, so why does it fail when I pass it as blank?
2. Why does it pass when I put acl as `bucket-owner-full-control` ? Since the acl is turned off in bucket, should it matter what acl value we are passing?
3. Why does aws cli work when acl is passed as blank?

PS : Enabling ACL might seem like a solution here but we can't do that because of security reasons.

I expect the upload to be successful.

Comment: Can you provide any code demonstrating the issue and any actual errors that you get?

Comment: Since ACLs are disabled on the bucket, can you simply avoid specifying an ACL? It probably works with `bucket-owner-full-control` because when ACLs are disabled it says "This bucket has the bucket owner enforced setting applied for Object Ownership". Thus, it is the new 'default' setting when ACLs are disabled.